# Tensorboard histogram_freq uses CPU instead of GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am using TensorFlow with Keras on my GPU and have been doing so successfully until now.

When I run Tensorboard with `histogram_freq = x` where `x != 0`, it uses the CPU at the end of each epoch when Tensorboard writes to logs vs the GPU for the entirety of training when `histogram_freq = 0`. I have seen this make training up to **five** times slower! I can confirm this is the cause as it is the only parameter used in Tensorboard during testing.

This [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3358) has been mentioned in previous questions but it is dissimilar in that their issue occurs when validation data is passed via a data generator and that histograms are not created - no reference to CPU or GPU. I do not use a data generator for validation and histograms are created on my end.

**Is anyone aware of a fix to prevent CPU being used when `histogram_freq` is enabled?**

Notes:

Training carried out by Keras `fit_generator`.

Training dataset passed by `ImageDataGenerator`.

Validation dataset is passed without data generator.

**Edit**

Switching Keras `fit_generator` out for `fit` crashes when attempting to write to Tensorboard logs when `histogram_freq != 0` but runs fine when `histogram_freq = 0`. The crash log is below. Notice it switches from GPU to CPU. Perhaps this could be something to work with?

```
 InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,48,48,1]
 [[{{node conv2d_1_input}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,48,48,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
 [[{{node dense_2/bias/read/_407}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_335_dense_2/bias/read", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,48,48,1]
 [[{{node conv2d_1_input}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,48,48,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
 [[{{node dense_2/bias/read/_407}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_335_dense_2/bias/read", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```